# Default constructors, initialization of POD and implicit type conversions in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have just watched Chandler's presentation on Clang at Going Native 2012. He presents the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S{ int n; };
struct X{ X(int) {}; };

void f( void* ) 
{
   std::cerr << "Pointer!\n";
}

void f( X ) 
{
   std::cerr << "X!\n";
}

int main()
{
    f(S().n);
}
```

Chandler states that this calls `f(void*)` for c++11 and `f(X)` for c++03.
He also states that the reason is that S().n is default initialised to 0, making it a `nullptr` constant.

Firstly am I right in assuming that the zero initialization of member variable n is compiler implementation dependent and NOT guaranteed by the standard (or did this change with c++11)? Chandler hints this is due to support for constant expressions but I still cannot fully follow his reasoning.

Secondly why would `f(X)` be called with C++03 and not c++11? I would of assumed that `f(void*)` would kick in regardless of the value of `S().n` over an implicit conversion to `X`

For Chandler's explanation see the following link, 45 minutes in:

[Clang: Defending C++ from Murphy's Million Monkeys](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Clang-Defending-C-from-Murphy-s-Million-Monkeys)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Firstly am I right in assuming that the zero initialization of member
>   variable n is compiler implementation dependent and NOT guaranteed by
>   the standard (or did this change with c++11)?

No, `S()` means value initialize in both C++03 and C++11.  Though I believe the wording for this is much clearer in C++11 than C++03.  In this case, value-initialization forwards to zero-initialization.  Contrast this with default-initialization which does not zero:

```
S s1;  // default initialization
std::cout << s1.n << '\n';  // prints garbage, crank up optimizer to show
S s2 = S();  // value initialization
std::cout << s2.n << '\n';  // prints 0
```

> Secondly why would f(X) be called with C++03 and not c++11? I would of
>   assumed that f(void*) would kick in regardless of the value of S().n
>   over an implicit conversion to X

In C++03 an `int` can never become a null pointer constant.  Once `0` is typed as an `int`, say by assigning it to an `int`, then it is forever an `int`, and not a null pointer constant.

In C++11, `S().n` is implicitly a `constexpr` expression with value `0`, and a `constexpr` expression with value `0` can be a null pointer constant.

Finally, this is not an intentional change on the part of the committee as far as I can tell.  If you're writing code that depends on this difference, you may well get bitten in the future if/when the committee corrects itself.  I would steer well clear of this area.  Use it to win bar bets -- not in production code.

Comment: Do you know if a defect report has been filed on this yet? I didn't see any but I might have missed it.

Comment: Thanks, I would never write code like that, just interested after watching Chandler's presentation...

Comment: Ah NVM I see now that with "an int" you mean "an int variable". I was confused and thought you meant to say that "0" is not an int or that int expressions never can be a null pointer constant.

Comment: CWG 903 is related, but I don't think that is it.  I'm not personally involved on this issue, and have just been eavesdropping on it (and then with only half an ear).  And I'll bet Johannes Schuab could describe the situation with much more precise language than I've done. There should be a new CWG issues list out just any day now, and maybe that will have a new issue on it.

Comment: I'm not personally involved either. But, Richard has recently brought up similar cases, such as "f(g());" when g is defined as "constexpr int g() { return 0; }". IMO the "g()" and "S().n" cases are sufficiently similar, in that both were introduced by C++11 and both are not desirable. In any case, both will be made invalid by resolution of CWG903.

Answer (score 5):

First, some clarification on the rules of initialization for both C++03 and C++11:

```
// This is default construction
S s;
// s.i has undefined value

// This is initialization from a value-initialized S (C++03 rules)
S s = S();
// s.i has been zero-initialized

// This is value initialization (C++11 rules)
// new syntax, better rules, same result
S s {};
// s.i has been zero-initialized
```

Then, remember that `int` is not convertible to `void*` so in C++03 `f(S().n)` will *never* call `void f(void*);` even if no other declaration of `f` is available.

What *is* possible in C++03 is to do `f(0)`, which will call `void f(void*);` even if `void f(X);` is present. The reason for this is that the `int` -> `X` conversion (a so called user-defined conversion) is not preferred to the zero integral constant -> `void*` conversion (which isn't a UD conversion). Note that it's also possible to call `void f(void*);` via `f( (int()) )` because `int()` is also a zero integral constant, even in C++03. (As usual the brackets are here to resolve a syntactical ambiguity.)

What C++11 changes is that now `S().n` is a zero integral constant. The reason for this is that `S()` is now a constant expression (thanks to *generalized* constant expression), and this kind of member access also is.